# Can I log SEVERE exceptions thrown by org.springframwork.jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I was wondering if there is a way to tell log4j to save this kind of exceptions.

At the moment, I am seeing this errors on my Tomcat Log, but due the error level is `SEVERE` and log4j has no such level of errors, I am not sure if I can capture it and save it on a different file...

So far at my `log4.properties` I have this

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, myLog
log4j.logger.org.springframework = WARN, myLog
```

the exception I am seeing on my tomcat log is being thrown by this class:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException
```

Any idea how to capture them?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j does not have severe but it does have fatal. Perhaps adding this to your logger will make it work?
Check this out for more:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#fatal(java.lang.Object)